# Calculation of ordered pair $(x,y,z)$ in $x^2 = yz\;\;,y^2=zx\;\;,z^2 = xy$

Tags: diophantine-equations, systems-of-equations

(1) Total no. of integer ordered pair $(x,y,z)$ in $x^2 = yz\;\;,y^2=zx\;\;,z^2 = xy$

(2) Total no. of integer ordered pair $(x,y,z)$ in $x+yz = 1\;\;,y+zx = 1\;\;,z+xy = 1$

My Try:: (1) Clearly $ x = 0,y = 0,z = 0$ are the solution of given equation

and from three equation we observe that $x,y,z$ has same sign.

Now If $x\neq 0,y\neq 0$ and $z\neq 0,$ Then $x^2-y^2 =-z(x-y)\Leftrightarrow (x-y).(x+y+z)  =0$

Means either $x=y$ or $x+y+z = 0$

$\bullet$ If $x = y$, The put in $z^2 = xy=x^2=y^2\Leftrightarrow z = \pm x = \pm y$

means  $x = y =z$

So $(x,y,z) = (k,k,k)$ where $k\in \mathbb{Z}$

$\bullet$ If $x+y+z = 0$, Then put in third $z^2 = xy\Leftrightarrow x^2+y^2+xy = 0$

So $x^2+y^2+xy = x^2+y^2+(x+y)^2 = 0\Leftrightarrow x = 0,y = 0,x+y = 0$

So $(x,y,z) = (0,0,0)$

So Given equation has Infinite solution

My Question is I have Calculate Right or not

If not plz explain me.

Thanks

Comment: Your solution is correct, though there is a slight typo: $\textbf{2}(x^2 + y^2 + xy) = x^2 + y^2 + (x+y)^2$.

Comment: Cute problem and solution!

Comment: Nice Question. But what is the second condition for? You didn't make use of it at all.

Comment: @AmireBendjeddou It seems to me that the second condition is not a condition, but a separate problem.  The second problem is included presumably just for context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint to (2):** subtract 2nd equation out 1st:
$$(x-y)(1-z)=0.\ \ \ (1)$$

**Addition:**

Similarly
$$(x-z)(1-y)=0,\ \ \ (2)$$
$$(z-y)(1-x)=0.\ \ \ (3)$$

If $z=1$, then $x+y=1, xy=0$ (from your $1$st and $3$rd equations) whence we obtain two solutions
$$z=1, x=1, y=0,$$
$$z=1, x=0, y=1.$$
Similarly for $y=1$ we get one more solution from ($2$):
$$y=1, x=1, z=0.$$

Further, let $x,y,z\ne 1$. Then $x=y=z$ and $x^2+x-1=0$ from your $1$st equation. Then we have two solutions:
$$x=y=z=\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
and
$$x=y=z=\frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2}.$$

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Thanks Boris Novikov  after your step I am getting $x = y$ or $z  = 1$

Comment: would you like to explain me after that, thanks

Comment: I will add the answer.